# Manually wiring bean (has autowired dependency): Failed to convert

Tags: spring

In a util class I want to use one of my services.
Now this service is wired, but the util isn't.

So in my Util class I do:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"context.xml"});
UserService userService = (UserService) ((BeanFactory)context).getBean("userServiceWired");
```

In my context.xml I do:

```
<bean id="userServiceWired" class="com.daniels.jack.service.userServiceImpl">
    <property name="restTemplate" value="restTemplateWired" />
</bean>
<bean id="restTemplateWired" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>
```

But I get:

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate'

On the `UserService userService = ...` line.

Comment: Note: You can simplify the 2nd line of your code to just `UserService userService = context.getBean("userServiceWired", UserService.class);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ref instead of value

```
<property name="restTemplate" ref="restTemplateWired" />
```